# Associate a new Google or Facebook login with an existing account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, google-oauth

I have just followed instructions in [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) to add Google as a login provider to my MVC 5 app. All seems to work OK, but when I log in via Google, it wants me to register the email/username provided by Google as a new account in my app. If I leave the email as is and click the 'Register' button, it tells me that address is already taken, as I have earlier registered on my app's own login provider.

How can I tweak the default code generated by the MVC project template to allow me to associate the Google login with an existing local account?

P.S.  I have exactly the same problem with Facebook.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Identity handles it the way it does on purpose, since there's no real way to verify the identity of the user by email alone coming from a third party. While the risk may be relatively low, it is possible that someone could create an account with a third party like Facebook, using an email address that does not belong to them, and then use that third-party login to impersonate an account at another website attached to the same email.

As a result, Identity only lets you create a new account with an external login when signing in, not attach to an existing one. However, once the user is authenticated by other means, methods are provided to associate additional logins.

If you're not concerned by the relatively mild security risk associated with just assuming that if the email matches it's the same person, then you need only modify `ExternalLoginCallback` in `AccountController.cs` to attempt to find the user by email:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginInfo.Email);
```

And then sign them in:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 20):

I totally second the points raised by @Chris Pratt
However i'm not sure the code used is enough to do what the OP asked.

adding this code in the default block inside ExternalLoginCallback should do the job

```
ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(loginInfo.Email);
if (user != null)
{
    var addLoginResult = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, loginInfo.Login);
    if (addLoginResult.Succeeded)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I was able to solve this issue that you are having.  This solution will allow you to register on the site with your email and if you then try to use Google to log in with the same Email address, you will not be requested to register and you will not generate any errors; you will be allowed to login if the email address that you logged in with locally is the same as your google account email.  I edited the Default ExternalLoginCallBack code that VS2015 generated with an if / else statement, which is checking for an existing email that matches the login Email.  I hope this helps you with your question, for I had the same issue and could not find an answer anywhere.  My multiple post requests were ignored and thankfully, I read one of the answers from this post that led me to my own solution that is working for me on VS2015 Core.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{       

    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
        return View(nameof(Login));
    }
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }            

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(email);
    if (user != null)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        // If user does not already exists, invite User to register.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(5, "User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
            email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = email });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I modified my answer and posted the solution instead.

Comment: Hi   https://mylive.stagingapplication.com starts with https but then it gives error of 400 and when changing to http ,it could not handle ExternalLoginCallback and gives 500 error. It work perfectly with https://localhost:4220/signin-google but giving on my live url

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR** you need to go through all scenarios manually in your `ExternalLoginConfirmation` function, and have a database table to be able to match membership user id with OAuth user id. This way you can "associate" multiple OAuth accounts with single local account.

Below is a code snippet from one of our projects - hopefully it's clear enough

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback()
{
    var returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["returnUrl"];

    var result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    if (result.IsSuccessful == false)
    {
        return this.View("ExternalLoginFailure", result);
    }

    // Login user if provider represents a valid already registered user
    if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
    {
        return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If the current user is logged in already - add new account
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
        return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(result.UserName);

    // so user is new - then create new membership account
    if (membershipUser == null)
    {
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        membershipUser = Membership.CreateUser(username: result.UserName, password: this.GetTempPassword(), email: result.UserName, status: out createStatus);
        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            this.emailService.SendWelcome(this, (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey);

            // Associate social network account with created membership account
            OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, result.UserName);
            OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

            return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // The problem occured while creating membership account
        this.ViewBag.Error = MembershipErrorNameProvider.FromErrorCode(createStatus);
        return this.View("CreateMembershipAccountFailure");
    }

    // If membership account already exists -> Associate Social network account with exists membership account
    OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, result.UserName);
    OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

    return this.RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

and `OAuthWebSecurity` is a helper class which deals with all providers you support:

```
public static class OAuthWebSecurity
{
        ....

    public static bool Login(string providerName, string providerUserId, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        var provider = GetOAuthClient(providerName);
        var securityManager = new OpenAuthSecurityManager(context, provider, OAuthDataProvider);
        return securityManager.Login(providerUserId, createPersistentCookie);
    }

    public static void CreateOrUpdateAccount(string openAuthProvider, string openAuthId, string userName)
    {
        var user = UserRepository.FindByName(userName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new MembershipUserNotFoundException();
        }

        var userOAuthAccount = UserOAuthAccountRepository.Find(openAuthProvider, openAuthId);
        if (userOAuthAccount == null)
        {
            UserOAuthAccountRepository.InsertOrUpdate(new UserOAuthAccount
            {
                OAuthProvider = openAuthProvider, 
                OAuthId = openAuthId, 
                UserId = user.Id
            });
        }
        else
        {
            userOAuthAccount.UserId = user.Id;
        }

        UserOAuthAccountRepository.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a pain in the butt that MS played this so simplistically, with not even a tiny mention of existing users? And for new users, instead of whatever registration details you would normally collect, the MS default just gets username/email. It should redirect to `Register` for new users.

Comment: well, everyone's use case is different - i prefer to think they created a framework you can relatively easy extend to your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is a normal behavior in MVC template**, since external logins attempt to create user and if the user's email (or external identity) already exists, attempt to signin. Furthermore, external login provider tries to assign an optional and unique identifier in your application (locally) separate from your external identity. **But, the following is strange**, as you said:

> If I leave the email as is and click the 'Register' button, it tells
>   me that address is already taken, as I have earlier registered on my
>   app's own login provider.

Which should work since each user's external id should be unique in other sites (I believe) unless you have registered multiple external accounts with the same identity since the table structures looks like this:

[image]

The column `UserId` will be matched with the bellow table's `UserId` column:

[image]

The message will be showed rarely, when a user tries to assign duplicate `Username` which will be enumerated with your email or identity name in other sites (e.g. somename@gmail.com will be *somename* as `Username`)

Comment: It's not the external provider's ID it complains is duplicate, but the email I use as my user name. I want 1 user name and many external providers. The setup the project template gives is a new user name and provider Id for each provider.

Comment: @ProfK My meaning refer to this example: I have two email addresses named amirhosseinmehrvarzi@gmail.com & amirhosseinmehrvarzi@outlook.com so what will happen in this case?

Comment: Then if you have local accounts for both, after using a third party sign in with one, you sign in locally as well and associate the third party token with your logged in address.

Comment: I think you have username conflicts when assign local username for external provider and this is *normal*. Do I think right?

Answer (score 0):

This following link shows you how to build an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that enables users to log in using OAuth 2.0  with credentials from an external authentication provider, such as Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Microsoft, or Google. For simplicity, this tutorial focuses on working with credentials from Facebook and Google existing accounts.

Refer this:

[MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

Comment: I already have logins via Facebook and Google, thanks, but that's not what I'm asking. If you follow the linked tutorial, you may experience the same problem I am actually asking about.